# How to return a default value when an Observer subscribes to my Observable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm still a rookie in RxJava and trying to implement something using it.

I have notifications counter in my Android application and I want to fetch the count from an API every five minutes, and I want to share this count to multiple activities. So I want to store the count in a pipeline so that each activity listens to that pipeline can get the last emitted value.

I started with an Object class and added two `BehaviorSubjects` one for providing the default value and the second to emit true value when the 5 minutes finish "to tell the activity that's listening if there's any" that you should fetch new count.

But the problem is that when I listen to the BehaviorSubject it emits all the data in the pipeline! How can I get only that last one

```
object RxBus {

@JvmStatic
var count: Int = 0

@JvmStatic
private var fetchData: Boolean = true

@JvmStatic
private var behaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<Any> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(CountEvent(count))

@JvmStatic
private var fetchSubject: BehaviorSubject<Any> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(FetchEvent(fetchData))

private val FIVE_MINUTES: Long = 1000 * 60 * 5

init {
    fixedRateTimer("countTimer", false, 0L, FIVE_MINUTES) {
        fetchSubject.onNext(FetchEvent(true))
    }
}

fun publish(event: Any) {
    if (event is CountEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "eventCount = ${event.count}")
        count = event.count
        fetchData = false
    }
}

fun listenToLoadEvent(): Observable<FetchEvent> {
    return fetchSubject.ofType(FetchEvent::class.java)
}


fun listen(): Observable<CountEvent> {
    return behaviorSubject.ofType(CountEvent::class.java)
}
```

Please note that I want to listen to both Subjects in `onResume` of each activity.. Is there any way to do that in a better way? And if not can you help me to just get the last emitted item only.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: BehaviorSubject will emit the last value and all next value, your Activity will receive the last value after subscription and all next event. you have to publish the new counter on behaviorSubject, on the publish method...

Answer (score 0):

```
    class CountEvent(val value: Int)

    object CounterManager {
        val counterDataSource = BehaviorProcessor.create<CountEvent>()

        val refreshNotifier = interval(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).publish()
                .refCount()

        fun publish(event: Any) {
            if (event is CountEvent) {
                counterDataSource.onNext(event)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is when I publish something it goes through the pipeline and when I listen to the BehaviorProcessor it emits all the data that have been published! I just want to get the latest one.. So for example when the third five minutes passes it emits 3 times so the api gets called 3 times in a row! How to solve this

Comment: it will emit 1 time to all active observer, you have to unsubscribe from refreshNotifier's stream on the onPause method...